# cocoa: how to create a custom view by IB?

Tags: cocoa

I want to create a custom view, say MyView, which is only containing a button and print out "hello my view" when I click it.  When next time I want to use it, I just need to add a custom view to window from IB, add MyView.m into project and set the class of custom view to MyView.

My question is :

1. I want to use IB to set the appearance of MyView, but I don't know how to get the corresponding view file : MyView.m in order to use the MyView.m file next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the subclassed view using code; for example:

MyView.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@implementation MyView : NSView
{
    IBOutlet NSTextField *_label;
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

MyView.m:

```
#import "MyView.h"

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        // Init here
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib:
{
    // Init here
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [_label setStringValue:@"hello my view"];
}

@end
```

You need to create your custom view layout using IB and change the owning class from `NSView` to `MyView` (using the 3rd tab if I recall).

Then connect the `_label` from the owning object on the left pane (Ctrl-drag) and connect the button action to the `buttonPressed:` method (Ctrl-drag).

Comment: If I want to use the MyView class in other project, can I use the MyView class by adding MyView.m file into that project without the xib file? The ABPersonView in object library can display the AddressBook-like interface, but I didn't find nib file about ABPersonView.

Comment: Yes; just copy the `.m`, `.h` and `.xib` files over.